# Leaflet - Allow dragging outside of map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I recently set up a non geographical map with leaflet using an image layer. This obviously is a stupid decision working with 'bigger' maps due to high memory usage and the need to load the big image file so I decided to use a tile layer instead.

Working mostly as expected aside from one thing: I can't seem to be able to drag outside of the map, it just jumps back so the map covers the screen. I'm not sure what causes that as I read that this behaviour usually needs to be set manually using maxBounds. Tried setting that to null, doesn't change. The only new thing introduced is Leaflet Rastercoords (https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords) which I'm unsure if that's causing the problems.

Any way to resolve that? Not sure where to look next.Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean exactly when you say "I can't seem to be able to drag outside of the map"?

Comment: take this example, https://commenthol.github.io/leaflet-rastercoords/ does it produce the same behaviour?

Comment: @GrafiCode yea exactly. I want to be able to drag basically as far as I want even if the map gets out of bounds.

Comment: did you set the `maxBounds` option? according to this: https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#map-maxbounds `When this option is set, the map restricts the view to the given geographical bounds, bouncing the user back if the user tries to pan outside the view.`

Comment: @GrafiCode I didn't, that's why I'm unsure why it's behaving that way. I tried setting it to null which should disable it but doesnt. It shouldn't be there in the first place without explicitly setting it as it defaults to null.

Comment: Sounds like a case of not having read the tutorial for `L.CRS.Simple`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez indeed i didnt. Mainly because I've been using that before and the behaviour started only after I switched to a tile layer instead of an image overlay. What tutorial are you actually referring to? I can't find anything in the Leaflet documentation that would help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the behaviour you want using the following work around:

```
 map.setMaxBounds(null); //map being the leaflet map.
```

This need to be called after the initialization of the map and of the raster coords layer.